# Does php function move_uploaded_file() cause disk io?

Tags: php, io

The /tmp dir and the destination dirs are on the same file system. If its handling large files (over 1GB), does this create any overhead in term of disk io?

Would it be better to simply have php put tmp files into the destination right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The /tmp dir and the destination dirs are on the same file system. If
>   its handling large files (over 1GB), does this create any overhead in
>   term of disk io?

No - if they are on the same filesystem, a very small amount of disk IO is used (equivalent to renaming a file).

Do note that in very many cases, `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` which is a filesystem in RAM, so do check this first (if it is, uploading to it is a bad idea since large concurrent uploads will fail).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the php source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L5812), it seems to try a rename before a copy. So if the files are indeed on the same filesystem, this should do only minimal file I/O.